# How rare is getting a mending villager on your first try for ten emeralds in Minecraft Bedrock?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

[image: Minecraft mending first try screenshot]

I screamed when I got that mending book on my first try because all day I've been having bad luck.

**How rare is getting a mending villager on your first try for ten emeralds?**

Answer (score 1):

There are 36 enchantments a villager can trade you, each with an equal probability of being selected. That gives a 1/36 probability of getting a Mending trade first try.

A Mending book will have a price from 10-38 emeralds. (Level 1 enchantments are 5-19 emeralds, but Mending is a treasure enchantment which doubles the price). That gives a 1/19 probability of getting a price of 10 emeralds for a Mending trade.

Multiply the two probabilities and you get 1/684, or **0.146%**. Very lucky!

Source: [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Trading#cite_note-enchanted-book-10)